# playwright cucumber json report need to generate with different names based on package.json execution scripts [ need diff report for each execution]

Tags: json, cucumber, report, cucumberjs, playwright

I am using playwright cucumber report.json

This is my cucumber.js
[image]

My package.json

```
"test:sit1rcb": "NODE_ENV=sit1 NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 cucumber-js -t @RCBSIT features/RCB/*.feature",
"test:sit3rcb": "NODE_ENV=sit3 NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 cucumber-js -t @RCBSIT features/RCB/*.feature",
"test:sit3csk": "NODE_ENV=sit3 NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 cucumber-js -t @CSKSIT features/CSK/*.feature",
"test:sit3kkr": "NODE_ENV=sit3 NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 cucumber-js -t @KKRSIT features/KKR/*.feature"
```

each script should generate a different report based on names ( RCB , CSK , KKR) say like CSK_report.json , RCB_report.json ...

my report path

[image]

When we execute this in windows server pipleline report is created and placed in a single location with the same file name.
This means that whenever the test scripts are executed in same time for RCB , CSK , KKR in each(SIT1 , SIT2) environment, the output will be overwritten and only the last executed test case result will be available for consumption

Please help me on following

1. How to rename the report.json based on package.json execution script , how to pass application pramameter to rename the report.json
2. OR we need to generate 3 different report in 3 folder based on application name which passing from package.json script
   how to change the cucumber.js config to generate multiple report in different folder and pass the report path for each execution with application name in it?

I am expecting to see

```
CSK_report_SIT3.json for npm run test:sit3csk
RCB_report_SIT3.json for npm run test:sit3rcb
```

please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass report file name from the test script of package.json file.

Create multiple const's in cucumber.js file for different names like CSK, KKR and RCB because you be will running different features files. Pass the REPORT_FILE_NAME from the package.json script, this will be passed to cucumber.js file and create report file accordingly. Also, will create unique file name and won't override.

Check below sample code.

cucumber.js

```
    const csk_test= `
   --require config/config.js 
  --require setup/assertions.js 
  --require setup/hooks.js 
  --require tests/sb/base-setup/baseSetup.js
  --require tests/sb/step-definitions/features/csk/**/*.js
   --format json:./reports/${process.env.REPORT_FILE_NAME}.json
  --format summary --format @cucumber/pretty-formatter 
  --no-strict 
  --tags "@CSK"
  --publish-quiet"
  },
  `;

    const rcb_test= `
   --require config/config.js 
  --require setup/assertions.js 
  --require setup/hooks.js 
  --require tests/sb/base-setup/baseSetup.js
  --require tests/sb/step-definitions/features/rcb/**/*.js
   --format json:./reports/${process.env.REPORT_FILE_NAME}.json
  --format summary --format @cucumber/pretty-formatter 
  --no-strict 
  --tags "@RCB"
  --publish-quiet"
  },
  `;
```

package.json

```
"test:sb:csk": "cross-env BROWSER='' HEADLESS=false LANGUAGE=english REPORT_FILE_NAME=CSK_Test_Report APP_LOAD_TIMEOUT=50000 --retry 3 cucumber-js --parallel 2 -p csk_test",

"test:sb:rcb": "cross-env BROWSER='' HEADLESS=false LANGUAGE=english REPORT_FILE_NAME=RCB_Test_Report APP_LOAD_TIMEOUT=50000 --retry 3 cucumber-js --parallel 2 -p rcb_test",
```